# Batch: Rename multiple files using input string

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I am trying to rename files after the user inputs a string they want to remove from the file name. This works fine except when I want to rename files that are in a different location than the script:

Here is what i have so far which works if I dont specific the file path (e.g. remove `C:\DATABASE\*.* /s`)

```
SET /P X=Type in the String that you want to remove and then press ENTER: 

set deletestring=%X%
for /f "delims==" %%F in ('dir C:\DATABASE\*.* /s /b ^| find "%deletestring%"') do (
    set oldfilename=%%F
    set newfilename=!oldfilename:%deletestring%=!
    Ren "!oldfilename!" "!newfilename!"
    )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead. e.g.:

```
remove *.*
```

or

```
remove "relative path\*.*"
```

or

```
remove C:\DATABASE\*.*
```

or

```
remove "C:\My Database\2010-*.bak"
```

Meaning that a directory and file mask must be specified. Here's the `remove.bat` file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set mask=%~1
set mask=!mask:%~dp1=!
if not exist "%~1" (
    echo No files found
    goto :eof
)
pushd "%~dp1"

SET /P X=Type in the String that you want to remove and then press ENTER: 

set deletestring=%X%
for /f "delims==" %%F in ('dir "%mask%" /s /b ^| find "%deletestring%"') do (
    set oldfilename=%%F
    set newfilename=!oldfilename:%deletestring%=!
    Ren "!oldfilename!" "!newfilename!"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your primary problem you are running into is that the 1st argument to REN can accept full path info, but the 2nd can only contain the new name without path info. You can use the `~nx` modifier to extract the name and extension from the full path reported by the FOR /F command.

Your FOR /F options are not reliable - it will break if the file name contains `=`. You want to set delims to nothing instead.

This problem is actually more complicated than it first looks. Your code will attempt to rename both files and directories. If you want to rename the directories then you must rename in reverse alpha order because the entire list is built before any thing is renamed. If you process in normal alpha order and rename a directory, then subsequent entries within that directory will not be found.

The FIND filter in the IN() clause is not necessary. Ideally your filter should only match the file or directory name, not the path. That is doable, but a bit tricky. I would simply skip the filtering in the IN() clause and do it in the DO clause.

A file or directory name can contain `!` character. But the FOR variable expansion will be corrupted if it contains `!` and delayed expansion is enabled. The problem can be avoided by toggling delayed expansion on and off within the loop.

It is possible for the entire name to be removed by the search and replace, but you cannot rename a file to nothing. So I added a test to ensure there is a name left.

```
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
SET /P "X=Type in the String that you want to remove and then press ENTER:"
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir C:\DATABASE\* /s /b ^| sort /r') do (
  set "old=%%F"
  set "file=%%~nxF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "new=!file:%X%=!"
  if defined new if !new! neq !file! ren "!old!" "!new!"
  endlocal
)
```

If you don't really want to rename directories then you need to add the /A-D option. I first thought you could use a FOR /R statement, but that could potentially cause the same file to be renamed twice. FOR /F buffers the entire result set before processing any files, but FOR /R does not.

```
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
SET /P "X=Type in the String that you want to remove and then press ENTER:"
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir C:\DATABASE\* /s /b /a-d') do (
  set "old=%%F"
  set "file=%%~nxF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "new=!file:%X%=!"
  if defined new if !new! neq !file! ren "!old!" "!new!"
  endlocal
)
```